# How to display Greek letters with subscript in rownames of an array?

Tags: r

I wanted to know how I put a subscript in the Greek sigma. For example: sigma_t^2.

I know I can write sigma ^ 2 as:

```
sigmaSq = '\u03c3\u00B2'
```

Comment: If you are looking to output the results to a latex table or similar, It will be easiest to do the fancy formatting in that construction.

Answer (score 1):

You can write [image] as

```
"\u03c3\u2082"
```

For a full chart of subscript conversions, refer to [this chart provided by Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf).

Comment: I need a letter as an undersigned.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? I don't know what 'as an undersigned' means.